# Ubuntu is caught in an infinite login loop

Tags: command-line, login

I am a Ubuntu newbie. I am running Ubuntu 16.04. Until yesterday my computer was fine. But today it got stuck in a login loop. I enter my username and password, it lets me to log in, but after a few seconds, it goes back to the log in screen. It keeps repeating forever. I went through the Ubuntu forums. They have suggested to login using Ctrl+Alt+f1 and then run mv .Xauthority Xauthority.backup. The problem is when I executed Ctrl+Alt+f1, a progress bar is shown forever and it never opens the terminal. I am not sure what to do next. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The most common reason I've had for login-loop is a lack of space in $HOME, as the GUI requires temporary work files to be created, and login will fair (ie. you're logged out without message) if insufficient space exists in $HOME to create said files).  I don't follow the progress-bar though; are you able to login via text terminal?  Did you check you have disk space etc? ($HOME refers to /home/$USER where $USER is your user id)

Comment: The Ctrl+Alt+f1 also stuck in an infinite loop. It never opened the terminal.

Comment: Did you try another combination, eg. I usually opt for Ctrl+Alt+F4, F3 etc as I've too had issues where ctrl+alt+F1 & f7 don't do what you expect them to (f1 becomes f2, f7 becomes f8)

Comment: I tried all the combinations but no luck!

Comment: Boot to Recovery Mode from the GRUB menu. Get to the root # prompt and type `sudo ls -al /home/your_username/.*thority`. Edit that output into your question. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Hi @heynnema, due to some reason I am unable to go into GRUB menu. I have restarted my computer, once the manufacturer's logo was displayed, I have started holding down the Shift key. Still, it goes to the GUI login mode. I was able to login as a gust. Is there anything I could do with that?

Comment: You can try the ESC key, instead of the RIGHT SHIFT key, to get to the GRUB menu (if you normally don't see it). Otherwise, the Guest account may not allow you to do the command that I gave you earlier... but you can try it.

Comment: ESC key also didn't bring the GRUB menu!

Answer (score 1):

If you still cannot bring up a terminal even with ctrl+alt+f1, it would be worth preparing a Live USB if you have access to another computer, booting from that, and checking that there is enough space, as [@guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216024/ubuntu-is-caught-in-an-infinite-login-loop#comment2044028_1216024) suggests.

Once you boot off the live USB, or manage to boot into a command line, use

`sudo blkid`

To find out the layout of your disks. Once you identify a likely suspect, for example `/dev/sda`, you can mount it using:

`sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt`

Once it's mounted, take a peek inside it to see which drive it is, and use:

`df -h`

To see what the capacity of the drive is (it will be the one that it says is mounted in `/mnt`).

Work your way though your drives/partitions until you see whether one of them (as @guiverc says, probably the one housing your `/home` folder, is full.

If you know which drive you home folder is in, go ahead and mount it as above, using the actual drive name, and use `df -h` to see whether it's full.

If they are, make space by clearing your caches. They usually are in `.cache`. The contents of this folder are safe to remove.

Comment: There is enough space. During one of the login loops, I have managed to check the hard drive. It has used 200 GB and 700 GB is free.

Comment: Yes, but how is your system laid out? Is the whole disk one ext4 partition or do you have multiples? Do you use LVM for a separate /home volume?